# Access query - does one field contain the value of another field

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to use a query to narrow the table down to only the rows in which the field [full name] contains the value in the field [first name].

For instance, if a row has "Blake Johnson" in [full name] and "John" in [first name] - this row will be included.
But if [full name] has "Garry Sways" and [first name] has "Swan" - this row will NOT be included.

I tried to use:

```
Like "*[first name]*"
```

In the criteria for [full name].

But it didn't work quite well.

Is there a "Contains" funciton for this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to do this? In Access itself, or in VB/VBA code?

Answer (score 2):

Just do this

`SELECT * From yourTable WHERE instr(fullname, firstname) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of query language you are using but you can use regular expressions to make a more granular version of "like"

For example, in MySql you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM 'foo' WHERE 'bar' REGEXP "^\$"
```

or in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fullname REGEXP (".*" + firstname + ".*");
```