# Access SQL query multiple updates

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hopefully you could help me with my idea:

I have a `table` that contains data and created some queries (around 10-15) to update the `fruitclass` field:

```
UPDATE [tblFruit] SET fruitclass = "Apple"
WHERE Fruit_Name Like "*apple*";

'this is a separate query
UPDATE [tblFruit] SET fruitclass = "Orange"
WHERE Fruit_Name Like "*orange*";
```

and so forth..

Then now, would like to ask if it is possible to combine those multiple queries into one? or I'll just stick with separate queries? Thanks!

Comment: Where do the fruits come from? Hard coded list? Another table? In the latter case you could write an update with a join on that table and a where similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090650/access-query-does-one-field-contain-the-value-of-another-field. If it is a hard coded list than stick to what you have.

Comment: Somehow, it was hard coded as I'm filling the `fruitclass` manually via query, which is based on whatever fruit like is in the `fruit_name` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `IIF()` conditional logic expressions:

```
UPDATE [tblFruit] SET fruitclass = IIF(Fruit_Name Like '*apple*', 'Apple', NULL),
                      fruitclass = IIF(Fruit_Name Like '*orange*', 'Orange', NULL),
                       -- ...add comma-separated expressions
;
```

Or nested `IIF()` but can get messy with 10-15 expressions:

```
UPDATE [tblFruit] SET fruitclass = IIF(Fruit_Name Like '*apple*', 'Apple',
                                       IIF(Fruit_Name Like '*orange*', 'Orange', NULL))
;
```

Comment: Thanks Parfaitm, i'll test your idea and it worked. However, I tried to use `Switch` and somehow it worked also. But of course i would like to know what is more optimized on the solutions that i have and I'm going to search for that. Thanks again!

Comment: Indeed, Access SQL uses `SWITCH`. Either are the same involving calculated expressions. The most optimized is to avoid `LIKE` and control *Fruit_Name* in data entry with combo boxes or directly enter into *Fruit_Class* among your users.